# Is there a list of official OSX keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I just accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> and the screen inverted the colors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a few resources for you:

- [Mac OS X keyboard shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343) (apple.com)
- [Useful keyboard shortcuts on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/138365/useful-keyboard-shortcuts-on-a-mac) (superuser.com)
- [Dan Rodney's List of Mac OS X Keyboard Shortcuts & Keystrokes](http://www.danrodney.com/mac/) (danrodney.com)
- [Table of keyboard shortcuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) (wikipedia.org)

You can also search for `shortcuts` from the "help" menu of almost any Mac application to obtain a list of shortcut keys.